# Different values on dereferencing a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am a novice c programmer when it comes to pointers.
I am trying to calculate the total prime numbers till a particular user input.
First,I am getting input in the main function and passing it to `printPrimes` function.In the new function i calculate the prime numbers and store them in an array and pass the pointer finally to main function.
My question is that why i am getting different outputs of the two loops one in the `main` function and other in `printPrimes`.
My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* printPrimes(int x)
{

    int i;
    int j;
    int y[30];
    int dummy=0;
    int count=0; 
    int *p = malloc(30*sizeof(*p));

    for(i; i<=x; i++)
    {
        for(j=2; j<i ;j++)
        {
            dummy=(i % j);
            if(dummy == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        } 

        if (dummy != 0 || i==2)
        { 
            y[count]=i;
            count++;
        }

    }

    p=y;

    for(i=0;i<=30;i++)
    {
    printf("%d , ",*(p+i));   //LOOP1
    }
    printf("\n");

    return p;
}

void main()
{
    int x;
    int *q;
    int j;
    int i;

    printf("enter the value of x , the number upto which you want primes");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    q=printPrimes(x);

    for(i=0;i<=30;i++)
    {
    printf("%d , ",*(q+i));   //LOOP2
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
enter the value of x , the number upto which you want primes23
2 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 11 , 13 , 17 , 19 , 23 , 110 , 0 , 0 , -298634272 , 32767 , 4195536 , 0 , -298634048 , 32767 , 2108875317 , 32711 , 0 , 0 , 1024 , 0 , -298634280 , 32767 , -298634280 , 32767 , 4196485 , 0 , -298634448 ,
2 , 606348324 , 3 , 0 , 11 , 13 , 17 , 19 , 23 , 110 , 0 , 0 , -298634272 , 32767 , 4195536 , 0 , -298634048 , 32767 , 2108875317 , 32711 , 0 , 0 , 1024 , 0 , -298634280 , 32767 , -298634280 , 32767 , 4196485 , 0 , -298634448 ,
```

What can i do for getting the same output? 
Regards.

Comment: Looks like this project is to learn about use of pointers. An important detail you should also learn is about memory leaks... while misused pointers are often (too) easy to discover, learning you have memory leaks and knowing to fix them can sometimes remain subtle.

Comment: 1) return local value. 2)always upto 30. 3) `i<=30` out of bounds.

Comment: Separate array for y not required when p has been allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the attempted array copying by:

```
p=y;
```

this in fact overwrites just the address of the newly allocated memory with the (stack) address of `y`. It does not copy the array elements, which is probably what you intended.

You need:

```
memcpy(p, y, 30*sizeof *p);
```

Or just stop using `y` altogether, and use `p` everywhere. Returning a `malloc()`ed pointer is perfectly normal and safe. Just remember that it becomes the caller's responsibility to call `free()` when the memory is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

That is because

```
int y[30];
```

allocates scope local memory on the stack. Accesses to that memory become undefined once the scope ends (in this case function return). Stacks are being reused by `printf` and overwritten.

Try

```
int *y = calloc(30, sizeof(int));
```

Normally if you wish to use stacks for arrays you allocate them in the function that calls and pass them to the function that populates it:

```
int* printPrimes(int x, int * y);
```

in `main`:

```
int y[30];
printPrimes(x, y);
```